# Compute the closest point from a specific point

Tags: javascript, css, math

I create a panorama has a compass in the middle, the compass is pointing towards the top center of the image, initially.

Now I want to move the compass with respect to this point, since it is a 360 panorama, it creates an adjacent duplicate. So what I wanted is to point the compass to the point to whichever point is closer as you move from left to right or right to left.

Here is the what I have done so far, which doesn't behave like what I wanted.

[image: diagram of 1st solution]

So here is the code for that: https://gist.github.com/joeyhipolito/8678bf35dba7795de4d5

What I did is that I created two points:

```
points.push({
  x: target.offset().left + (windowWidth) / 2,
  y: target.offset().top
});

points.push({
  x: (target.offset().left + (windowWidth) / 2) + (common.width / 2),
  y: target.offset().top
});
```

And then try to calculate which points is closer to the reference by pythagorean theorem

```
var closestPoint = points[0];
var closestValue = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(points[0].x, 2) + Math.pow(points[0].y, 2));

for (var i = 1; i >= points.length; i++) {
  var z = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(points[i].x, 2) + Math.pow(points[i].y, 2));
  if(z < closestValue) {
    closestPoint = points[i];
    closestValue = z;
  }
};
```

What do you think I am missing out?

Comment: Is it a Maths question instead ?

Comment: Well programming part math too right?

Comment: Maybe. Can you list out your formula so that we can trace your codes?

Comment: there, I edited the question

Comment: Your code here is fine, console.log your `points` variable, see your points are right.

Comment: Your approach is quite confusing. Why not use the x position of image to rotate your compass rather than using arbitrary points? Lets say north have some x_offset, then your rotation value can be:
`rotation=((x+x_offset)/image_width*360)+rotation_offset`
This is just a thought that your approach may not be better one. If I missed the point please clearify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
//                 ↓↓
for ( var i = 1; i >= points.length; i++ ) {
  // ...
};
```

to

```
//                 ↓
for ( var i = 1; i < points.length; i++ ) {
  // ...
};
```

---

Another way to do this is using [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). It may not be as quick, but it may be more semantic:

```
function distFromOrigin( point ) {
  return Math.sqrt( Math.pow( point, 2 ) + Math.pow( point, 2 ) );
}


var closestPoint = points.reduce(
  function( closestPoint, currPoint, index, array ) {
    var currDist = distFromOrigin( currPoint ),
      closestDist = distFromOrigin( closestDist );

    if ( currDist < closestDist ) {
      return currPoint;
    } else {
      return closestPoint;
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have an issue with the control of your for loop. This loop:

```
for (var i = 1; i >= points.length; i++) {
};
```

(note the exit condition) does not run, because 1 (initial value of `i`) is immediately below the array's length, which is presumably at least 2. On the other hand, if the array length was at most 1, then this loop will never terminate, as `i` will keep increasing, and the `i>=length` statement remains true.

You probably want to change that exit condition to i<=length, then the minimum-finding logic should be fine.

Comment: Array length is two, I already set the `closest` variable to be the first element in the array that is index 0, that is why I started at 1

Comment: @JoeyHipolito with this condition  `i >= points.length` you are trying to fetch elements out of array bounds.

Comment: @JoeyHipolito I understand you starting at 1, but why is the exit condition "while i is **above** point-count" instead of "while i is **below** point-count"? This way, your loop either runs 0 times or infinite times, because if i was > points.length to begin with then it will be still bigger after i++.